# What is the relationship between words like see and show , eat and feed called as?

Tags: grammar

Isn't "I will make you see." same as "I will show you."

does there exist a word for every such word 
lik id I want to say I will make you work , what word would I use 
or maybe for something else

What are the words see and show(making someone see) , known as ?

Comment: The full OED says [In all the continental West Germanic languages the verb has the meaning ‘to look at’ (compare sense 1), and the complex sense development shown in English, in particular the development of the causative sense ‘to cause to be seen’ (which may be considered the core meaning of all the later sense branches), is unparalleled.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/178737?rskey=W88Olu&result=3#eid) That's to say, in *English* you can "show" *(**demonstrate**)* something just using ***words***, for example. It's not exclusively "visual".

Comment: Note that even blind people have no problem with using *I see what you mean* in the sense of ***I understand***. And unless I'm mistaken, there are no specific English verbs with the meaning *cause or enable someone to **hear / smell / taste / feel** something*.

Comment: I am not specifically pointing out this example but giving this edcample for the the words that satisfy this relationship .

Comment: Well, I'm sure there are many verbs that can work both ways - but offhand, I can only think of [*doing the prosecutor's job for him, helping him **sweat the suspect***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22him+sweat+the+suspect%22) (transitive), where intention is to (intransitively) *make **the suspect sweat***. But that's not exactly what you're asking about, is it?

Answer (score 1):

If I *make* you *do* something, that involves some force of some kind.
I can *show* you, but you might not *see*.

I struggle sometimes to *make my students see* how easy English is to learn. I show them different examples but they will not see. I create diagrams to "direct their eyes" as it were, to *help them see*, but they will not see.

Comment: I am not specifically pointing out this example but giving this edcample for the the words that satisfy this relationship .

Comment: @JIM Are you looking for a generic term for the relationship between one person doing X causes the other person to do Y?

Comment: +1 "You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make it drink."

Comment: I mean suppose I want to say like "I made him drink water " or maybe"I made him do work " so there any word for term"made him work " or "made him drink " . I thought that words like 'see' and 'show' had some name for the relationship

Comment: Hi @JIM, did you find the correct answer?